# raycast не видит объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d

Создаю луч из камеры, то есть центра экрана на позицию мыши, однако луч не видит объекты с тегом Enemy. С интернетом сверился, код более менее правильный, так почему враги не видны рейкасту?

Код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using static UnityEngine.GraphicsBuffer;

public class Choseenemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera Cam;
    public Material NewMat;
    public Material OrigMat;
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray;
    void Start()
    {
        ray = Cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Cam = Camera.main;

    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.tag == "Enemy")
            {
                Debug.Log("hit");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("No hit");
            }
            //if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider != null)
            //{
            //    if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
            //    {
            //        Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
            //        hit.collider.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().material = NewMat;
            //    }
            //}
            ////else hit.collider.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().material = OrigMat;

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Красные цилиндры это враги, на них висит тег Enemy и коллайдеры как надо]

[image: объект Enemy, при старте я их создаю из префаба]

Comment: Вы создаете луч только один раз в Методе Start, а как я понимаю его нужно обновлять каждый кадр чтобы он соответствовал позиции мыши 
Попробуйте перенести "ray = Cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);" и "RaycastHit hit;" в метод Update.

Comment: Сделал, теперь я понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в том, что я создаю ray только один раз в start, нужно было перенести строку `ray = Cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);` в update